# imported function not working python

Tags: python

This is an extract of the code:

```
import game_state

game_state
Out[65]: <module 'game_state' from 'C:\Users\Bob\Python\Pygame practice\Connect Four\game_state.py'>

game_state.get_available_moves(columns)

moves = game_state.get_available_moves(columns)

print moves
None

get_available_moves(columns)
Out[69]: [[5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6]]
```

Here is the "get_available_moves" function which is saved under "game_state.py"

```
def get_available_moves(columns):
    available_moves = []
    for i in xrange(7):
        for j in xrange(5, -1, -1):
            if columns[j, i] != 0:
                continue
            else:
                available_moves.append([j, i])
                break
    return available_moves
```

When I just use the function "get_available_moves", it performs correctly. However when I try to import it and use it, it returns no output. I'm very new to coding and would appreciate any help as to why this is happening. I can provide the code for the function too, if the problem doesn't lie here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show the code. Note that the extract you have posted is confusing as you seem to be accessing it in two different ways - are you sure `get_available_moves` is the same as `game_state. get_available_moves`?

Comment: Well I believe I have done something wrong, and therefore it isn't, I just can't figure out what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `game_state.get_available_moves` simply doesn't return anything. If you would look at it's code you would see that it either has no `return` statement, or (less probable) it has `return None`.

It seems that `game_state.get_available_moves` and the "local" `get_available_moves` are not the same function.

Comment: How would I edit the code to get the "get_available_moves" function to output correctly? I'm sorry but I don't quite understand, I thought the game_state was just a module from which I was importing my functions.